# How to convert 1400-1500 to 2pm - 3pm?

Tags: vb.net, datetime, time

I am receiving data representing a time slot from a service as a string in the form of:

> 1500-1600

This meaning 3pm to 4pm.

I will have a list of these e.g.

> 1200-1300
>
> 1300-1400
>
> 1400-1500

and I have to represent this in the UI as

> 12pm - 1pm
>
> 1pm - 2pm
>
> 2pm - 3pm

Unfortunately this list could be in a random order.

My question is is there any way of using the DateTime object to be able to convert a 24 hour time to a 12 hour time and also is there a way of ordering times in order?

At the moment I am feeling I will have to write a custom parsing function but wondering if anyone knows how to do this better? or could advise on how they would achieve this.

Comment: Sorry i just updated the title.

It is VB.NET

Comment: Are you sure with "12pm - 1pm"? Shouldn't this be "12am - 1pm"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the four digit strings (1200, 1300) and it will always be four digits (e.g. 9 am is 0900) then you can call the static [`ParseExact` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) on the [`DateTime` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) like so:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(time, "HHmm", formatInfo);
```

`formatInfo` is an [`IFormatProvider` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx) implementation.

If you have a three digit string, then you can use this:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(time, "Hmm", formatInfo);
```

However, I would recommend using a four-digit string because of the ambiguity presented with a time like "121".

From there, if you want to output am/pm, etc, etc, you would just call the [`ToString` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx), passing the following format:

```
string ampm = dt.ToString("htt");
```

Answer (score 11):

I'll assume you know how to split the times into "1400" and "1500". The easiest way (IMO) would be to use

```
DateTime.ParseExact(input, "HHmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

That will return a `DateTime` with today's date and the given time. You can then format that `DateTime` however you want.

Alternatively, you could parse "1400" as an integer, then find the minutes and hours using Math.DivRem, dividing by 100. Personally I prefer to use DateTime though.

Comment: Thanks.  The following from casperOne's post is very helpful also 

string ampm = dt.ToString("htt")

Answer (score 1):

I would first split on the " - " to get the two different strings, then use the `DateTime.ParseExact()` method to look into converting it to a useable datetime object

Answer (score 0):

Try this to convert and output to whatever format you need

```
Dim aDateTime As DateTime
aDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "HHmm", Nothing)
Dim outputToDesiredFormat As String = dt.ToString("h:mm tt")
```

Answer (score -1):

Custom parsing should be trivial.  Split at the '-' and parse each time; remove the last two digits to get the minutes, the remaining one or two to get the hour, and you're done.

If you need them in order, sort them.

Update the question or leave a comment if you need more help than this.